# Why lumen doesn't have config cache?

Tags: php, performance, caching, lumen

In my lumen project, the env load is talking around **85%** of total API request time.

[image: 85%]

I'm just wondering why lumen doesn't support config cache. Or is there any workaround to reduce the env load time?

I'm just trying the way laravel creates the config cache on deployment itself by using `config:cache` command. Create a custom command to create a cache file building our own logic.

Is there any better approach or packages available?

Comment: 85% of what amount? File access should be *extremely* quick, and the "read from file" bit should be the fastest part. Are you on a NFS filesystem or some other reason it'd be super slow?

Comment: @ceejayoz yes I'm on Amazon efs

Comment: OK, in that case... be sure not to use a file-based cache! 

Answer (score 1):

Lumen is a micro-framwork and does not support all niceties of it's bigger brother Laravel.

It seems also others have this issue with Lumen and someone create a package - [orumad/lumen-config](https://github.com/orumad/lumen-config-cache).